# How to pass a function as callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this JS code:

```
Download.prototype.insert = function(stocks, exchange, cb){
    var self  = this
      , count = stocks.length      

    stocks.forEach(function(stock){     
        save(stock, done)
    })

    function save(stock, cb){
        self.mysql.query("my query", [exchange.id, stock.Symbol], function(err, rows){
            if (rows && rows.length > 0) 
                self.mysql.query("my query", [rows[0].id, stock.DateTime, stock.Close], cb)
            else cb()   
        })      
    }

    function done(){                
        count--
        if (count === 0) return cb()        
    }
}
```

as you can see I pass a callback to the `save()` function, I would like to know if i can separate the queries to avoid using of `function(err, rows){ .... }`

the problem is that function wait two parameters `err` and `rows`, so How can I also pass a custom third parameter (the `cb()` function) ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the way you have done is ok, because inside the anonymous `function(err,rows)`, you are still able to reference `cb` from outer scope. You dont have to pass `cb` again.

Comment: This was also my first thought, but I think Dail just wants to separate the queries and was looking for a way to pass the callback function, including the "done" callback parameter, to the mysql.query ..

Comment: afaik it is down to the person writing the callback to to include the any required params, i.e. jquery's callbacks can accept params it is down to you as to whether the callback you are passing takes the params see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/EBLx8/1/) and play around with the params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right ^^

To wrap your callback parameter, you can create a function that returns an anonymous function (the actual callback). The cb parameter gets wrapped into the context of the anonymous function:

```
function queryDetails(cb){
  return (
    function(err, rows){
      if(rows && rows.length < 0){
        //mysql.query ...
      }else{
        cb()
      }
    })
 };
 mysql.query("query", ...., queryDetails(doneCallback));
```

Have fun!